# how to make countdown timer from firebase database for android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, countdowntimer

I wanted to make countdown timer from firebase database. the counter should be synced to all users equally
and users should not control or manipulate the timer.

I tried to use the starting time to be network provided date and final finishing time to be set in firebase database. the countdown timer should count the difference of both time.

Here is my code.

manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"
        tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />
```

main counter fragment

```
private CountDownTimer mCountDownTimer;
private TextView mTextViewCountDown;
private String dateEnd="";
private long mTimeLeftInMillis;
    
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    dashboardFragment= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dashboard, container, false);

    startTimer();

    currentUser= FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    mAuth=FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    timeRef=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

    InitializeFields();
    mTimeLeftInMillis=dateFormat();

    return dashboardFragment;
}

private long dateFormat() {

    long diff=0;

    SimpleDateFormat formatter=new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy, HH:mm");
    formatter.setLenient(false);

    long endTime=0;
    Date endDate;

    try {
        endDate=formatter.parse(dateEnd);
        endTime=endDate.getTime();
    }catch ( ParseException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

    diff=endTime-startTime;
    return diff;
}

private void startTimer() {

    mCountDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(mTimeLeftInMillis, 1000) {
        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            mTimeLeftInMillis = millisUntilFinished;
            updateCountDownText();
        }
        @Override
        public void onFinish() {

        }
    }.start();
}

private void updateCountDownText() {

    int days=(int) mTimeLeftInMillis/(24*60*60*1000);
    int hours=(int) mTimeLeftInMillis/(60*60*1000)%24;
    int minutes = (int) mTimeLeftInMillis / (60*1000)%60;
    int seconds = (int) mTimeLeftInMillis / 1000%60;
    String timeLeftFormatted = String. format(Locale. getDefault(), "%02d:%02d:%02d:%02d",days,hours, minutes, seconds);
    mTextViewCountDown. setText(timeLeftFormatted);
}

private void InitializeFields() {

    mTextViewCountDown = dashboardFragment.findViewById(R.id.count_down_timer);
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    final DatabaseReference timeRef=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Time").child("endTime");
    String timeSettings = android.provider.Settings.System.getString(
        getActivity().getContentResolver(),
        android.provider.Settings.System.AUTO_TIME);
    if (timeSettings.contentEquals("0")) {
        android.provider.Settings.System.putString(
            getActivity().getContentResolver(),
            android.provider.Settings.System.AUTO_TIME, "1");
    }


    timeRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            dateEnd=(String) snapshot.getValue();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

        }
    });
    updateCountDownText();
    startTimer();
}
```

The counter gets the difference but doesn't count. Each time i restart the app it gets new refreshed time the only problem is not counting.

i dont know how to fix it. any one please.

Answer (score 1):

To my mind, there are several problems.

`startTimer()` in `onCreateView()` is useless because no variables have been initialized.

`InitializeFields()` is useless too because it is a common practice to retrieve graphical components just below the `inflate` operation and you don't need to same an instance of the created view.

In don't know what `timeRef` refers to in `onCreateView()` because it is not used and you have another variable with the same name in `onStart()` method.

Your `updateCountDownText()` modify a graphical component. So, it must be called on UI Thread.

And then, in `onStart()`, you are launching the timer before retrieving `dateEnd` variable because the listener pattern in asynchroneous.

Here are some fix about what I've said

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dashboard, container, false);
    mTextViewCountDown = dashboardFragment.findViewById(R.id.count_down_timer);

    currentUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    timeRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

    mTimeLeftInMillis = dateFormat();

    return v;
}

private long dateFormat() {

    long diff = 0;

    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy, HH:mm");
    formatter.setLenient(false);

    long endTime = 0;
    Date endDate;

    try {
        endDate = formatter.parse(dateEnd);
        endTime = endDate.getTime();
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

    diff = endTime - startTime;
    return diff;
}


private void startTimer() {

    mCountDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(mTimeLeftInMillis, 1000) {
        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            mTimeLeftInMillis = millisUntilFinished;
            updateCountDownText();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {

        }
    }.start();
}

private void updateCountDownText() {

    getActivity().runOnUiThread(() -> {
        int days = (int) mTimeLeftInMillis / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
        int hours = (int) mTimeLeftInMillis / (60 * 60 * 1000) % 24;
        int minutes = (int) mTimeLeftInMillis / (60 * 1000) % 60;
        int seconds = (int) mTimeLeftInMillis / 1000 % 60;
        String timeLeftFormatted = String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "%02d:%02d:%02d:%02d", days, hours, minutes, seconds);
        mTextViewCountDown.setText(timeLeftFormatted);
    });
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    final DatabaseReference timeRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Time").child("endTime");
    String timeSettings = android.provider.Settings.System.getString(
            getActivity().getContentResolver(),
            android.provider.Settings.System.AUTO_TIME);
    if (timeSettings.contentEquals("0")) {
        android.provider.Settings.System.putString(
                getActivity().getContentResolver(),
                android.provider.Settings.System.AUTO_TIME, "1");
    }

    timeRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            dateEnd = (String) snapshot.getValue();
            updateCountDownText();
            startTimer();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

        }
    });
}
```